# WebView background color

Tags: android, android-webview

I am looking for a custom background color for my WebView, and I have found a possible solution like this,

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#123456"));
```

But I don't want to hard-code my color value. So I tried this,

```
  wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Integer.toString(R.color.lawry_bgcolor)));
```

which literally showed me error,

```
06-17 13:37:11.307: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(854): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:   Unknown color
06-17 13:37:11.307: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(854):     at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:222)
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not try:

```
  wv.setBackgroundColor( getResources().getColor( R.color.lawry_bgcolor ) );
```